# Retrieving lines from textArea - Java

Tags: java, textarea

I have created a textArea with two lines of text present by default when
the program is run. The user is supposed to type any word, and press enter.
They may do this as many times as they want- meaning that the last word typed by them won't necessarily always be on the same line.
I want to be able to access the last word they typed, which would be on the last line, however am unable to find any way to do so. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `getText` and then split the resulting using something like `\n`

Comment: A little more detail would be really helpful - I'm new to coding and can't decipher what that means.

Comment: Please add more relevant tags to your question.

Comment: `JTextArea#getText` will return the `String` (text) from the `JTextArea`.  Using `String#split`, you can split the text on a common delimiter, in this case the newline character (`\n`), into a `String` array.  You can get the last element in the array, which should be the last word. You may need to check for empty lines though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to access the last word they typed, which would be on the last line,

You can use the `Utilities` class to help you out:

```
int end = textArea.getDocument().getLength();
int start = Utilities.getRowStart(textArea, end);

while (start == end)
{
    end--;
    start = Utilities.getRowStart(textArea, end);
}

String text = textArea.getText(start, end - start);
System.out.println("(" + text + ")");
```

The above will return the last line that contains text. The while loop handles empty lines at the end of the text area.